# Use MiniLib with CMake (C++)

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I want to create a C++ project using a version of MiniLib (https://github.com/SirJonthe/MiniLib). I use CLion as IDE, which uses CMake to build my project. How is it possible to use the MiniLib library? Including it with include_library didn't work.

Comment: You must remove the standard include paths from the compilation process, and add your own. Then you need to remove the standard libraries when linking, and add your own there as well.